# Update z-index on image using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this JQuery UI sortable list that has draggable elements and when I drag it from the bottom to the top, it saves a value corresponding to it's place in the list and saves it in the database. This works! But I need an image on my webpage to update simultaneously by chaning it's z-index. So once a item from the list has been moved to another place in the list, the z index gets stored in the database (which works) and then I need it to change the specific image to using that same z-index. My AJAX code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    stop: function (event, ui) {

        var data = $(this).sortable("serialize");

        //These next 2 lines are just a poor attempt to achieve what I want:
        var change_zindex = 1;
        document.getElementsByClassName('item2')[0].setAttribute("alt", change_zindex);


        // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "database/update_settings_sort.php"
        });
    }
});
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Well I hope you have some suggestions or advice. Thanks in advance, please tell me if you want me to provide more code.

Edit:

This is what I have now:

```
var change_zindex = 1;
         document.getElementsByClassName('item2')[0].setAttribute("alt", change_zindex);
```

Only problem is to 
1. Know what the `change_zindex` variable shall be equal to.
2. Be able to do it with all items on the list and not just only `item2`. I could use something like `'item' + img_id` but I don't know how to retrieve that id. Hmm Thanks all

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: @Wex I'm stuck in two parts right now, first thing is what `var change_zindex` shall be equal to, in order to change the z-index to the same value as the value that is set into the database. Second thing is to know what item was just moved by the `document.getElementsByClassName('item' + data)[0].setAttribute("alt", change_zindex);` I guess I can write `item + data` maybe? mhm

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine but make sure you are getting the value for variable 'img_id' in the following three lines

```
    var zindex = document.getElementsByClassName('item' + img_id)[0].getAttribute('z-index');
    var change_zindex = 1;
    document.getElementsByClassName('item' + img_id)[0].setAttribute("z-index", change_zindex);
```

Comment: I have changed the 3 lines to something better. This works okay but what value do you think I would set to `change_zindex` in order to make it know where the item was dropped to?